# How do you convert YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z time format to MM/DD/YYYY time format in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

For example, I'm trying to convert 2008-09-26T01:51:42.000Z to 09/26/2008. What's the simplest way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).parser.parse() to parse the date string into a timezone aware datetime object, then use strftime() to get the format you want.

```
import dateutil.parser

d = dateutil.parser.parse('2008-09-26T01:51:42.000Z')
print(d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))  #==> '09/26/2008'
```

Comment: Why `import datetime`? You don't seem to be using it.

Comment: @jhrr `dateutil.parser.parse` converts the string object to datetime object. That `datetime` library is to handle datetime-string conversion fo this object ie. `d.strftime`.

Answer (score 50):

I know this is really old question, but you can do it with python datetime.strptime()

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ" 
>>> datetime.strptime('2008-09-26T01:51:42.000Z', date_format)
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 26, 1, 51, 42)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the format string. Useful for both strptime and strftime!

Comment: An even shorter format to do it is using directives: `"%Y-%m-%dT%X.%fZ"` :-)

Answer (score 24):

```
>>> import time
>>> timestamp = "2008-09-26T01:51:42.000Z"
>>> ts = time.strptime(timestamp[:19], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
>>> time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y", ts)
'09/26/2008'
```

See the documentation of the Python [`time`](http://python.org/doc/2.5/lib/module-time.html) module for more information.

Comment: I know that in this case they are not relevant, of course, but is there a way to handle milliseconds short of stripping them?

Comment: Unfortunately, the strptime function doesn't seem to have a conversion operator for milliseconds.

Comment: Although the answer seems quite complete, if you want to read more on the python/date-time subject I'd suggest this page 

http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html

Comment: While this solution does get the desired result, it does not take into account the timezone (in this case UTC). This could be undesirable in some cases.

Comment: Jeremy: the OP didn't ask anything about local time conversion. The solution above manipulates the components of the timestamp without regard to time zone.

Comment: It appears the Python3 does handle microseconds, see the [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). I am parsing this exact format with `strptime` and the format `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ`.

Answer (score 3):

`2008-09-26T01:51:42.000Z` is an ISO8601 date and the format can be very diverse. If you want to parse these dates see the python wiki on [working with time](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WorkingWithTime). It contains some useful links to modules.

Answer (score -3):

```
def datechange(datestr):
dateobj=datestr.split('-')
y=dateobj[0]
m=dateobj[1]
d=dateobj[2]
datestr=d +'-'+ m +'-'+y
return datestr
```

U can make a function like this which take date object andd returns you date in desired dateFormat....