# python convert datetime formatted string to seconds

Tags: python, datetime, epoch, strptime

I am trying to decode a date string to epoch but I have difficulties getting the timezone. This is the last modified date from Amazon S3 keys.

```
time.strptime(key.last_modified, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Z')

ValueError: time data u'2013-10-20T00:41:32.000Z' 
            does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Z'
```

If I get rid of the timezone (.000Z) it works, but I need the timezone as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you convert YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z time format to MM/DD/YYYY time format in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214777/how-do-you-convert-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-000z-time-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy-time-forma)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.000Z` is not recognized as a timezone offset. In fact, you have *milliseconds* and a timezone (`Z` is UTC), and *officially*, `time.strptime()` parser cannot handle milliseconds. On *some* platforms `%f` will parse the microsecond portion, then discard the information.

The [`datetime.datetime.strptime()` class method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), however, *can*, but *not* the timezone, however; parse the `Z` as a literal and it works:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime(key.last_modified, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import time
>>> example = u'2013-10-20T00:41:32.000Z'
>>> datetime.strptime(example, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 20, 0, 41, 32)
>>> time.strptime(example, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=20, tm_hour=0, tm_min=41, tm_sec=32, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=293, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Note that on my Mac OS X laptop, `%f` works for `time.strptime()`; it is not guaranteed to work everywhere, however.

Converting a `datetime.datetime()` object to a time tuple can be done with the [`datetime.timetuple()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple).

Comment: Oh dear ... I suppose I'm so used to using `datetime` (and it's in your answer) that I forgot there even was a `time.strptime`.  Next time I suppose I'll read the question (and answer!) more thoroughly.  Sorry for jumping the gun.

Answer (score 4):

`2013-10-20T00:41:32.000Z`

In this string, 32.000 is seconds with precision to the thousandth place. 'Z' is the timezone for UTC, colloquially known as Zulu time.

If you take a look at this [table](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) in the Python 2.x docs, the `%S` argument can only handle the range [00, 61] inclusive with no decimal points. The 61 is to account for leap seconds. This is why your string formats don't match. You'll need to remove the three zeros following the decimal point from your string.

Comment: Damn, beaten to the punch... but Martijn's answer is much more thorough.

Answer (score 0):

#To convert date, timestamp string into seconds.

`enter code here`import datetime enter code here`time_in_seconds = datetime.datetime.strptime('13:12:2022,23:00:00', '%d:%m:%Y,%H:%M:%S')).timestamp()`

However, the following code can be used to ensure that conversion is considering the time zone.
`import datetime`

`import pytz`

`datetime_tuple = datetime.datetime.strptime('13:12:2022,23:00:00', '%d:%m:%Y,%H:%M:%S')`

`output : datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 13, 23, 0)`

`timezone = pytz.timezone('Appropriate_Time_Zone')`

`datetime_timezone = pytz. utc.localize(datetime_tuple)`

`time_in_seconds = datetime_timezone.timestamp()`

## For setting the time zone pytz provides a list of timezones:

e.g., timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Vienna')