# python datetime timezone .000Z not recognised format

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to parse the following date time:

`stripped_most_recent = 2017-03-22 14:07:50.000Z`

`timestamp = (datetime.datetime.strptime(str(stripped_most_recent), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))`

Returns the following error:

`ValueError: time data '2017-03-22 14:07:50' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`

Whereas, this timestamps causes no problems at all:

`2017-03-22 14:07:30.181Z`

I have seen this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214777/how-do-you-convert-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-000z-time-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy-time-forma?noredirect=1&lq=1), but dont understand why .000 does not work, whereas anything else is fine.

I think the solution is to remove the .000 completely from the string? As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472859/python-convert-datetime-formatted-string-to-seconds): What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

PS I have also tried:

`timestamp = (datetime.datetime.strptime(str(stripped_most_recent), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z time format to MM/DD/YYYY time format in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214777/how-do-you-convert-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-000z-time-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy-time-forma)

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate question answers your question.