# How to convert datetime string to another format

Tags: python, date, parsing

How to convert `2015-10-22T22:24:00.000` to the date and time string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm` in order to obtain `2015-10-22 22:24`.

Comment: Have you actually *tried anything?* What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dateutil.parser.parse() parse the date string into a timezone aware datetime object, then use strftime() to get the format you want.

For better explanation [goto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215313/5313264)