# Timestamp YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD python

Tags: python, django

How can i get datetime in ISO 8601 date format (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD). Example 2019-02-26T09:30:46+03:00

I tried using

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.now()
d.isoformat()
```

But the output is now correct

> '2020-07-29T15:47:46.974744'

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z time format to MM/DD/YYYY time format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214777/how-do-you-convert-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-000z-time-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy-time-forma)

Comment: The format is different, notice +xx:xx at the end also I dont need milliseconds -> [.974744]. I need something like 2019-02-26T09:30:46+03:00

Answer (score 2):

```
d = datetime.now()
d.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Do note that %z will return empty if its a naive datetime object

This should give you the format you're looking for.
https://strftime.org/
This is a good reference on the available formats

Comment: I tried I am getting '2020-07-29T16:04:43+0300' , the end part need to be +03:00

Comment: After @JoeTan's code, you can use `d = d[:-2] + ':00'` to solve your problem @EmmanuelMtali